# Sollte man  „der/die/das“ oder „er/sie/es“ als Personalpronomen verwenden?

Tags: difference, personal-pronoun, style

Ich hatte immer gedacht, dass man nur „er“, „sie“ und „es“ als Personalpronomen verwendete:

> Der Stuhl war nicht so billig. Er ist sehr alt.

Allerdings habe ich den folgenden Satz in meinem Deutschkursbuch gefunden:

> Wo sind denn meine Ohrringe? Die lagen doch früher noch auf dem Tisch.

Ich würde aber "sie lagen" sagen. Was ist der Unterschied? Sind beide korrekt?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Beide Formen sind korrekt.

*der*, *die* und *das* sind in den Beispielen, die du anführst, allerdings keine Personalpronomen, sondern **substantivisch gebrauchte Demonstrativpronomen**.

*Jener, jene, jenes* und *dieser, diese, dieses* werden in der gesprochenen Sprache oft durch *der da, die da, das da* o. ä. ersetzt.

Demonstrativpronomen können stellvertretend für ein Substantiv oder als Artikelwörter vor einem Nomen verwendet werden. Sie können sich rückweisend auf etwas vorher Erwähntes (= [anaphorisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphorik)) oder vorausweisend auf etwas noch zu Erwähnendes (= [kataphorisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kataphorik)) beziehen:

rückweisend:

> Wer ist der Typ? Den kenne ich bereits.

vorausweisend:

> Wir lieben diejenigen, die uns zum Lachen bringen.

Answer (score 12):

Splattne gibt bereits die korrekte Antwort, ich möchte nur anfügen, dass, wenn es um Personen geht, der/die als unhöflich gelten:

> Frau Meier ist nicht da. *Die* ist wieder krank.

So spricht man nur über Personen, die man nicht mag; es liegt im Beispiel ein leicht vorwurfsvoller Ton im Satz.

> Frau Meier ist nicht da. Sie ist wieder krank.

...ist hingegen eine einfache, wertfreie Feststellung.

Comment: Grundsätzlich kann ich da zustimmen, es ist besser, diese Verwendung zu vermeiden. Allerdings ist sie in der Umgangssprache durchaus auch ohne negative Wertung gebräuchlich.

Comment: Es liegt vielleicht am gewählten Beispiel. Hier z.B. sieht es anders aus: "Frau Meier ist in Urlaub. Die kommt am Montag wieder ins Büro." Rein stilistisch würde ich zu "Sie kommt..." raten.

Comment: Ihr habt natürlich Recht: Umgangssprachlich wird auch der/die benutzt; schön ist es aber nicht. Es ist ein verbales mit-dem-Finger-auf-Leute-zeigen. Und das macht man ja nicht.

Comment: Eventuell ist es auch im Zusammenhang mit einer Frage weniger wertend: "Wo ist denn Frau Meier? - Die kommt gleich." Auf jeden Fall nur mündlich zu verwenden.

Comment: @OregonGhost Du hast recht, in dem Fall finde ich es überhaupt nicht wertend. Tatsächlich empfände ich in dem Fall sogar "Sie kommt gleich" als etwas seltsam. Wahrscheinlich, weil der Sprecher des Satzes Frau Meier vorher gar nicht selbst erwähnt hat.

Comment: @fzwo: Das klingt plausibel. Sprache wäre so einfach, wenn es nicht so viele subtile und subjektive Unterschiede gäbe... ;)

Comment: Der/die/das mit einer Person zu kombinieren dient dazu sie zu "versächlichen", wenn jemand Sprachgefühl hat ist es sehr wahrscheinlich, dass er es als entweder unhöflich oder sogar als beleidigend auffasst. Darum gibt es ja die eigenen Personalpronomen. Insofern gebe ich @fzwo vollkommen recht. Generell sollten Namen nicht mit Artikel belegt werden. Kleiner Typo unterlief dir in "Ant**ow**rt"

Comment: "Wo ist Müller?" "Er ist wieder im Sportschaustudio; der hat wieder das Tor des Monats geschossen." - sicher nicht beleidigend, wenn es auch etwas distanzlos wirkt. Und Distanzlosigkeit wird oft beleidigend eingesetzt, aber nicht jede Distanzlosigkeit ist beleidigend. Der splattne hat's mal wieder als erster gewußt. :)

Answer (score 4):

Eine Ergänzung vielleicht noch:

Ich habe die Erfahrung gemacht, dass es durchaus auch auf die Region ankommt, welches Verhältnis von der/die zu er/sie in der gesprochenen Sprache vorherrscht.

Im Rheinland hat der/die zum Beispiel eine sehr hohe Frequenz in der mündlichen Kommunikation und wird auch (natürlich je nach Sprecher) fast durchgehend neutral für Personen eingesetzt. Man kann das natürlich auch abwertend meinen, aber das wird dann eher durch Ton und Kontext ausgedrückt.

Für Dinge würde ich niemals er/sie benutzen, es nur selten, aber auch das ist vermutlich regional unterschiedlich.

Also:

> Wo ist mein Bruder? - Der/(er) ist im Wohnzimmer. (neutral)
>
> Hast du den Typen da eben gesehen, ich mag den nicht. (abwertend, aber wegen Kontext)
>
> Hast du den Typen da eben gesehen, ich finde den/ihn voll nett. (die Version mit *ihn* klingt etwas förmlich für meine Ohren)
>
> Wo ist der Schirm? - Der liegt unterm Tisch.
>
> Hast du meinen neuen Schirm gesehen; ich habe den/(ihn) gestern erst gekauft.
>
> Wo sind die Ohrringe? - Die liegen doch da!
>
> Hast du meine neuen Ohrringe gesehen; ich habe die/(sie) gestern erst gekauft.
>
> Wo ist mein Buch? - Das liegt da auf dem Tisch.
>
> Hast du mein neues Buch gesehen; ich habe es/das gestern gekauft.

In Klammern jeweils Alternativen, die nicht *falsch*, aber doch etwas unnatürlich sind.

Answer (score 0):

> A: Wo ist denn Frau Müller heute?
>
> B: **Die** hat heute frei.

würde ich sagen.

> B: **Sie** hat heute frei.

hört sich für mich komisch an.