# Meaning of "der" in a sentence

Tags: pronoun, definite-article

What does the second *der* mean in the following sentence?

> Einzig der Fluss Kabul, so heißt übrigens auch die Hauptstadt von Afghanistan, fließt in den Indus und *der* mündet am Schluss in den Indischen Ozean.

Source: https://www.kinderweltreise.de/kontinente/asien/afghanistan/daten-fakten/steckbrief/

Comment: I was reading out this earlier today, see related questions in [English](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7897/43989) and [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/784/43989)

Answer (score 7):

The second *der* is not the definite article, even if it looks the same, but a [Demonstrativpronomen, engl. demonstrative pronoun](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/pronomen/demonstrativpronomen), which refers back to *Indus*.

This would be easier recognized, if *dieser* had been written instead, but *der* is completely correct, too.

Even better (since it more clearly points out the change of the subject) would be:

> ... in den Indus, dieser wiederum mündet in den Indischen Ozean.

(I don't see a benefit of *am Schluss* and therefore dropped it.)

Comment: If I understand it correctly (it's not easy to master), in this case using *der* is similar to stressing "it" in English. So "Only the Kabul River ... flows into the Indus and at the end IT (the Indus) flows into the Indian Ocean." Since the Kabul is the subject of the previous clause, using *er* instead would imply you're still talking about the Kabul. In written English stress wouldn't work so you'd end up having to repeat "the Indus" to avoid ambiguity. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @RDBury Yes, a demonstrative pronoun is like verbally pointing your finger at it - So, it's clearly a stress.

Comment: @RDBury While your translation may be idiomatic, the literal/technical one would be: *Only the Kabul flows into the Indus and **this** [in turn] flows into the Indian Ocean*. I think *it* has not quite the same amount of 'denonstrativeness' as *der*. When used like this, *der/die/das* is really like a shorter/lighter form of *dieser/diese/dieses* ('this', 'that').

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Thanks, the difference is subtle but I see your point. An alternative, in German and English, is to go with a relative clause: *... , der am Schluss ... mündet.* -- "... which flows into ...". It's not quite the same emphasis but it is unambiguous, and I think it would be the best option in written English. The paper [here](https://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/k.vdeemter/pages/bosch.pdf) has the example "John  called  Fred  a  Republican.  Then  he  insulted him." The second sentence has complete different meanings depending on which words are accented.